# How to detect peaks in a linear decreasing dataset?

Tags: matlab

I have a dataset that looks like:

[image: dataset]

Which is a kind of signal decreasing linearly with altitude, but eventually with peaks, and I would like to detect at which altitude those peaks appear, not where the maximum is but where it starts to increase and decrease.

I've tried to detect the difference between the point n+1 and n-1 but the increase is quite small and I would like to detect when it starts increasing and/or decreasing.

I also have used the `movmean` function in order to reduce the noise. However, the difference between each point is too small for the algorithm to detect the peak.

Furthermore, not all the data has these values, meaning that I cannot use something like "detect when the signal reaches values of 19" because sometimes the values are smaller.

Summarising, the point is that the data is always linearly decreasing, and those peaks can appear, and I want to detect where they start and finish.

If someone can help me, I would be very grateful, thank you very much!

Comment: `findpeaks` maybe? Then some derivatives

Comment: I think a combination of `transpose` and `findpeaks` should do